# KCF Tracker Doesn't work in different versions of opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

In my previous version of opencv - 4.2.0.34 - I was able to track an object using

```
tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
ok = tracker.init(image, bbox)
```

and ok would be true. But now with opencv - 4.5.1.48 - the same code results in ok always being None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's supposed to return `None`.  [The documentation says so](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html#a7793a7ccf44ad5c3557ea6029a42a198).

This means that if you want to know whether you have found the object within the frame successfully, you run the [`update`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d0a/classcv_1_1Tracker.html#a92d2012f576e6c06eb2e257d110a6529) method and it will return `True` or `False` to let you know whether the object was located successfully.  There is no longer a need for a return flag upon initialization since it's superfluous.  However, OpenCV will throw basic assertions if you provide nonsensical inputs into the `init` method.

Comment: Thanks a ton, should've checked the documentation for any changes .

Comment: My pleasure!  Sometimes it takes a good look at the documentation to get the answer you need.  This was definitely a change from previous OpenCV versions though.